# Rails sending duplicated/wrapped parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, coffeescript

I create in my coffeescript code an object to pass via ajax `post` request which looks like this:

```
{"Category":[{"value1a":"v1a", "value2a":"v2a"}, {"value1b":"v1b", "value2b":"v2b"}]}
```

Via this code

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'master/create',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(tickets)
        })
```

`tickets` is the name of the object made.

but Rails is interpreting this like

```
Parameters: 
{"Category"=>
  [{"value1a"=>"v1a", "value2a"=>"v2a"}, {"value1b":"v1b", "value2b":"v2b"}], 
  "master"=>
    {"Category"=>[{"value1a"=>"v1a", "value2a"=>"v2a"}, {"value1b":"v1b", "value2b":"v2b"}]
    }
}
```

Where is this "master" coming from, and why is this happening?

If it helps, master is the name of the controller.

Comment: what's in the `tickets`?

Comment: it's the object right above the ajax code.

Comment: Ah right, sorry.